# Cannot connect ssh between two linux machines on same network using public and private keys

Tags: ssh

I am trying to connect to `machine2`, which is running Ubuntu 19.10, with `machine1`, running Ubuntu 18.04.5 using ssh. When I attempt to use the ip address of `machine2` to connect from `machine1` I get the following message:

```
[machine1_username]@[machine1_host]:~$ ssh -v [machine2_username]@ip_address
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/[home_directory]/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [ip_address] [[ip_address]] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [ip_address] port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host [ip_address]port 22: Connection timed out
```

When I attempt to connect to `machine2` from `machine1` using the hostname I get the following message:

```
ssh: could not resolve hostname [hostname].local: Name or service not known
```

Neither command prompts me for a password. The public key has been stored in the `authorized_keys` file in `.ssh` directory on `machine2` manually but as I said, I don't get that far.

My ufw settings on `machine1` and `machine2` allow traffic on that port, ssh has been installed on both machines, `openssh-client` has been installed on `machine1` and `openssh-server` has been installed on `machine2`. The nmap command on both machines indicates port 22/tcp is open for ssh connections. I've also verified that `machine2` is listening on `Port 22`.

`sshd_config` on the server:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

`ssh_config` on the client:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

From the client, `machine1`:

```
[machine1_username]@[machine1_host]:~$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

From the server, `machine2`:

```
[machine2_username@[machine2_host]:~$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I've made sure I'm using the correct IP address and user name. Considering they are on the same network, I know I'm doing something dumb.

Comment: Have you started SSH daemon on the destination machine? Show an exact command you're using to connect.

Comment: The ssh daemon starts on the local machine just fine.

Comment: Can the machines ping each other?

Comment: `machine1` cannot ping `machine2`. It works the other way around, which doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with authentication. It looks a fw issue.
Please check `sudo dmesg` for the connection drops ...

Comment: I checked but I'm not sure what to look for a quick google search did not indicate what flag I should be looking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider your first attempt

> When I attempt to use the ip address of machine2 to connect from
> machine1 I get the following message:
>
> ```
> ssh: connect to host [ip_addr] port 22: Connection Timed out
> ```

This means that `machine1` was able to route to `ip_addr` and attempt the connection. However, `machine2` has a firewall configured to `DROP` all inbound connection attempts. You need to relax that to allow the connection attempt.

There is a difference between the error message generated when trying to connect to a client where `sshd` is not listening (or the firewall is set to `REJECT` incoming connections) and one where the host does not exist (or the firewall is set to `DROP` incoming connections)

```
ssh: connect to host […] port 22: Connection refused      # Host not listening, or REJECT
ssh: connect to host […] port 22: Connection timed out    # No host, or DROP
```

Now consider the second attempt

> When I attempt to connect to machine2 from machine1 using the hostname
> I get the following message:
>
> ```
> ssh: could not resolve hostname [hostname].local: Name or service not known
> ```

This is telling you that `machine1` could not resolve the name `hostname` (did you mean `machine2`?) to an address, so it didn't know where to try and connect. Enable Bonjour/Avahi on `machine2` so that it can advertise its address to `machine1`.

Comment: I think you mean `machine1` could resolve the hostname. That is the machine I attempt to connect from. I think you have the machines mixed? Or am I confused?

Comment: ufw settings state that communication on port 22 is allowed on both machines.

Comment: @user138669 please see the explanation in my answer

Comment: I turned the firewall off and got the same message.

Comment: Is `machine1` blocking _outbound_ connections?

Comment: Port 22/tcp settings are the same. I also turned this machine off tried again. I've tried the connection with ufw turned off on both machines separately and simultaneously.

Comment: 1. Is the IP address really that of the target machine?

Comment: 2. Are the machines on the same network? If not, are you absolutely sure that there isn't another firewall somewhere between them?

Comment: They are on the same network. the ufw setting for `machine1`, the machine i am attempting to connect FROM lists port 22 as `ALLOW IN`. The same is true for `machine2`. Can't find anything that explicitly explains how to change it to `ALLOW OUT`, if that matters.

Comment: I also set it up so both machines would allow communication with the other's ip address, specifically. Same message.

Comment: Plus, the default in `machine2` is to allow all incoming, at the moment.

Comment: You say you uncommented the `Port` setting in `/etc/sshd_config`. Did you set it to a value other than `Port 22`, and have you restarted `sshd` since making that change?

Comment: I removed the comment symbol on `Port` and `PasswordAuthentication` in the `ssh_config` file on `machine1`, the machine I'm attempting to connect FROM. I haven't changed anything else in any other configuration files on either machine.

Comment: uncommented the `Port` setting in the `sshd_config` file and left it at 22. Also uncommented the authorized_keys option. Same message.